# Not able to access rest API in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot application with pom.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>hotel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Hotel project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my Application class is in `com.demo.`, and my controller is in the `com.demo.controller` package. Given below my controller class.

```
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HotelController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String getString() {
        return "Helloworld";
    }
}
```

After running the Spring Boot application I have tried to access my rest API at `localhost:8080/test`, but the API is not accessible. It says "This site can't be reached".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing the method type GET, you can do by two options:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getString() {
    return "Helloworld";
}
```

Or

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getString() {
    return "Helloworld";
}
```